# Join data in different folders considering the file names

Tags: r

Good morning everyone,
I have a problem that I didn't find anything in my searches.
Well, I have two folders each with 121 files (.txt) with temperature data (one with maximum temperature and one with minimum temperature) for sub-basins.
the data have the same names and the same number of lines (13654).
[image: folder structure] 
[image: data structure]

I want to join this data by names,
so that the files have data of tmp min and tmp max separated by commas.

[image: new data struture]

I want to apologize in advance for not attaching a reproducible example on this, so I am attaching the screens with the patterns and also part of the original data for download.

link to download https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DdE1eWK0xf9XBRdocI-bN1flxDRggLVv/view?usp=sharing
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a data.table approach.

```r
baseDir <- "~/ex/ex1/data_T/"
setwd(baseDir)
library(data.table)
files <- list.files(recursive=TRUE, pattern = "*.txt")
DT <- rbindlist(lapply(setNames(as.list(files), files), fread), idcol = "file")
DT[, `:=` (MinMax = factor(grepl("max", file), labels = c("min", "max")),
           p = as.numeric(gsub("(.*/p)([0-9]+)(.txt)", "\\2", file)))]
DT[, idx := 1:.N, by=list(p, MinMax)]
setkeyv(DT, c("p", "idx"))
DT <- dcast(DT[, -"file"],  p + idx ~ MinMax, value.var="V1", fun.aggregate = NULL)
DT
#>          p   idx        min        max
#>      1:  1     1 19800101.0 19800101.0
#>      2:  1     2       23.2       34.1
#>      3:  1     3       24.0       32.6
#>      4:  1     4       23.3       34.1
#>      5:  1     5       23.8       34.6
#>     ---                               
#> 216252: 16 13512       24.0       36.5
#> 216253: 16 13513       22.6       34.5
#> 216254: 16 13514       22.1       35.1
#> 216255: 16 13515       22.1       35.9
#> 216256: 16 13516       22.7       36.4
head(DT[, .(min, max)])
#>           min        max
#> 1: 19800101.0 19800101.0
#> 2:       23.2       34.1
#> 3:       24.0       32.6
#> 4:       23.3       34.1
#> 5:       23.8       34.6
#> 6:       23.2       33.9

## now you can save csv files
fwrite(DT[, .(min, max)], file = "MinMax.csv", col.names = FALSE)

## or write them out into separate files:
outfiles <- split(DT, DT$p)
lapply(seq_along(outfiles), function(x) fwrite(outfiles[[x]][, .(min, max)], file = paste0("MinMax_p", x, ".csv"), col.names = FALSE ))
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>